# Is it possible to overcome this 32-bit limitation?

Tags: perl, 32bit-64bit

The `cartesian` function inside [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen) seems to be limited by the unsigned 32-bit upper limit on my 64-bit Windows OS:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Gen '*';
use 5.010;
use bigint;               # This didn't help either

say $List::Gen::VERSION;  # 0.80

my $diameters = range( 1, 175 );
my @five_in_a_row = ( $diameters ) x 5;

my $combinations = cartesian { \@_ } @five_in_a_row;

say 0+@$combinations;   # Should be 175**5 == 164_130_859_375
                        # prints -1+2**31  ==   2_147_483_647
```

---

Is there any way to overcome this limitation? My Perl build details are below.

> ```
> > perl -v
> ```
>
> This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 3 (v5.12.3) built for
>   MSWin32-x64-multi-thread (with 9 registered patches, see perl -V for
>   more detail)

Comment: OS "bitness" doesn't matter. Looks like it's a 64-bit build of Perl, so 64-bit ints should be used. Please confirm that `perl -V:ivsize` is 8.

Comment: @ikegami : `ivsize='8';`

Comment: I get "Not an ARRAY reference" inside `cartesian`. It's trying to array-deref the contents of `@five_in_a_row`.

Comment: @ikegami : I'm using an older version of `List::Gen` (0.80). Works for me.

Comment: @ikegami: You could alternatively try `my @five_in_a_row = ( [ @$diameters ] ) x 5;`. Or forget about the range altogether and use `( [ 1..175 ] ) x 5;`. The issue is still there.

Comment: Poking around the latest [`List::Gen` source code](https://metacpan.org/source/ASG/List-Gen-0.974/lib/List/Gen.pm), I can see that there is some index limitation based on `POSIX::DBL_MAX()`. On a side note `perl -MPOSIX -E "say POSIX::INT_MAX;"` returns 2147483647, but I don't see List::Gen using it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point, the tied interface to generators will always be limited, due to perl fitting array indicies into 32 or 64 bit integers.  Beyond that range, you can use the object oriented interface to generators, which is not limited to `2**31-1` and is much faster than then tied interface.

```
my $combinations = cartesian {\@_} map {range 1 => 175} 1 .. 5;

say $combinations->size; # 164130859375
```

and to get an element:

```
my $x = $combinations->get(164130859374);
```

or

```
my $x = $combinations->(164130859374);
```

And I will add auto-detected 64-bit limits to the list of improvements to make before the next release.

Answer (score 2):

List::Gen explicitly limits the result to 2**31-1.

```
sub FETCHSIZE {
    ...
    my $fetchsize = sub {
        my $size  = $realsize->();
        $size > 2**31-1
              ? 2**31-1
              : $size
    };
    ...
}
```

You could change it to

```
use Config qw( );
my $max_iv = $Config::Config{ivsize} == 8 ? 2**63-1 : 2**31-1;

sub FETCHSIZE {
    ...
    my $fetchsize = sub {
        my $size  = $realsize->();
        $size > $max_iv
              ? $max_iv
              : $size
    };
    ...
}
```

Comment: Weird. My code now returns 922_102_127, which is even smaller than before :/